# How we calculate distance between two co-ordinate. ArangoDB

Tags: node.js, distance, arangodb, aql

I have a Users table that contains latitude and longitude attribute for every user. So I need to calculate the distance between two users in AQL Query.

I have done the same in Orientdb with the below query.

```
var laltitude = CURRENT_USER_laltitude;
var longitude = CURRENT_USER_longitude;
var query = "select distance(latitude, longitude,"+laltitude+","+longitude+") as distance from users";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a js file distance.js (or whatever you want to name it) and put below code as below.

```
/* distance.js */
'use strict';

function gdistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, radius) {
    if (!latitude1 || !longitude1 || !latitude2 || !longitude2) { 
        return null; 
    };

    var lat1 = Number(latitude1), lon1 = Number(longitude1);
    var lat2 = Number(latitude2), lon2 = Number(longitude2);

    radius = (radius === undefined) ? 6371e3 : Number(radius);

    var R = radius;
    var φ1 = (lat1 * Math.PI / 180), λ1 = (lon1 * Math.PI / 180);
    var φ2 = (lat2 * Math.PI / 180), λ2 = (lon2 * Math.PI / 180);
    var Δφ = φ2 - φ1;
    var Δλ = λ2 - λ1;

    var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2)
          + Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2)
          * Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;     // Meters
    var d2 = d / 1000; // Meters to KM
    return d2; 
}

module.exports = gdistance;
```

Now open Arango Console with `arangosh`. This will open with `_system` database by default. So if you have other than this database like me then use `db._useDatabase("myDatabase")` command to change database.

Now write below commands to add custom to your desired database.

**Version 2.8**

```
db._useDatabase("myDatabase");
var aqlfunctions = require("org/arangodb/aql/functions");
var f = require("/path/to/file/distance.js");
aqlfunctions.register("geo::gdistance", f, true)
```

**Version 3.0+**

```
db._useDatabase("myDatabase");
var aqlfunctions = require("@arangodb/aql/functions");
var f = require("/path/to/distance.js");

i.e.
var f = require("/home/ubuntu/distance.js");
var f = require("distance.js");

# If you want to remove this group's UDFs (User defined functions)
# aqlfunctions.unregisterGroup("geo");
aqlfunctions.register("geo::gdistance", f, true);
```

Now use in your AQL queries as below.

```
LET distance = geo::gdistance(attrbute_name.latitude, attrbute_name.longitude, @your_latitude, @your_longitude)
```

For more references with [here](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1846).

Answer (score 1):

Currently ArangoDB can only give you distances when you use the Geo index to return you the distance of your search start to the point matching your condition:

```
FOR doc IN WITHIN(@@collection, @lat, @long, @radius, @distanceAttributeName)
  RETURN doc
```

You could however [use a user defined AQL function](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/AqlExtending/index.html) to extend AQL. User defined functions are implemented in Javascript, which is luckily used by [Chris Veness to explain howto calculate distances](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

With ArangoDB 3.0 we most probably will support the arithmetic operations to calculate this in AQL.

I will edit this post with more details and examples soon.